# How do i write a code to display every letter in every JPanel, and how do I rotate. (JFrame, NetBeans)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm new to Java, and I was assigned in my class to develop a code for the following question, I was only able to do the design, after that I didn't know how to continue adding the actions to every button.

This is the question:

https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/write-java-application-creates-frame-similar-one-shown--four-letter-word-shown-four-panels-q52352988

If anyone has ever solved it, please share it.
Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: I'm confused.  The only button on the JFrame is the "Rotate" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'm not providing the entire code.  I will provide snippets.

Here's the GUI I created.  I wish I could show it as an animated GIF.

[image: Rotate Word GUI]

I added a stop button to stop the word rotation.

I wrote the code by breaking the problem down into smaller and smaller steps, then coding each of the steps.  I ran many tests of the GUI before I finished it.  Some of the tests failed, and I had to revise the code.

I wrote 6 classes.  The main class created the `JFrame`, the letter panel group, and the control panel on the bottom.  I wrote a `LetterPanel` class to create one letter panel.  I wrote 3 `actionListener` classes, one for the `JComboBox`, one for the rotate button, and one for the stop button.  I wrote an `Animation` class that rotates the letters every second.

Here are the colors I used to get the 4 shades of green.

```
    Color[] colors = { new Color(50, 117, 1),
            new Color(65, 159, 0), new Color(88, 201, 5),
            new Color(107, 242, 2)
    };
```

Setting up the main `JPanel` to hold the 4 `LetterPanel` objects was a bit tricky.  Here's how I did it.

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
```

The `LetterPanel` class extended a `JPanel` and overrode the `paintComponent` method.  First, I called the `super.paintComponent` method.  Always call the `super.paintComponent` method first.  Then, I painted the background color.  Then, I painted the letter.

To paint the letter in each `LetterPanel`, I used the following code.

```
    /**
     * Draw a String centered in the middle of the panel.
     *
     * @param g2d The Graphics2D instance.
     * @param text The String to draw.
     * @param font The Font to draw with.
     */
    public void drawCenteredString(Graphics2D g2d,
            String text, Font font) {
        FontMetrics metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics(font);
        int x = (getWidth() - metrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
        int y = ((getHeight() - metrics.getHeight()) / 2) +
                metrics.getAscent();
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
    }
```

The JComboBox actionListener gets the selected word from the JComboBox.  The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), tells you exactly how I set up the word JComboBox.

The rotate button `actionListener` checks if both `JCheckBox` fields are checked.  Then it checks if neither `JCheckBox` field is checked.  Finally, it starts an `Animation` thread.

The stop button stops the `Animation` thread.

The `Animation` thread rotates the word and pauses 1 second to allow you to see the rotation.

Here is the run loop.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            updatePanel();
            sleep(1000L);
            if (leftSelected) {
                word = rotateLeft(word);
            } else {
                word = rotateRight(word);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here are my rotation methods.

```
    private String rotateLeft(String word) {
        return word.substring(1) + word.substring(0, 1);
    }

    private String rotateRight(String word) {
        return word.substring(word.length() - 1) +
                word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
    }
```

### Edited to add;

I'd forgotten I'd answered this question.  Enough time has passed so I'll post the entire application.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I can post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class RotateWord implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RotateWord());
    }

    private Animation animation;

    private JCheckBox leftBox;
    private JCheckBox rightBox;

    private JComboBox<String> wordComboBox;

    private JFrame frame;

    private LetterPanel[] letterPanel;

    private String word;

    public RotateWord() {
        this.word = "WORD";
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Rotate Word");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createWordPanel(word), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createControlPanel(word),
                BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createWordPanel(String word) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));

        Color[] colors = { new Color(50, 117, 1),
                new Color(65, 159, 0), new Color(88, 201, 5),
                new Color(107, 242, 2)
        };

        letterPanel = new LetterPanel[word.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            letterPanel[i] = new LetterPanel(colors[i],
                    word.charAt(i));
            panel.add(letterPanel[i]);
        }

        return panel;
    }

    public void updateWordPanel(String word) {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            letterPanel[i].setLetter(word.charAt(i));
            letterPanel[i].repaint();
        }
    }

    private JPanel createControlPanel(String word) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        String[] words = { "ABLE", "BATH", "EXIT", "WORD" };
        wordComboBox = new JComboBox<>(words);
        wordComboBox.setSelectedItem(word);
        wordComboBox.addActionListener(new WordListener());
        panel.add(wordComboBox);

        leftBox = new JCheckBox("Left");
        panel.add(leftBox);

        rightBox = new JCheckBox("Right");
        panel.add(rightBox);

        JButton rotateButton = new JButton("Rotate");
        rotateButton.addActionListener(new RotateListener());
        panel.add(rotateButton);

        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.addActionListener(new StopListener());
        panel.add(stopButton);

        return panel;
    }

    public class LetterPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private char letter;

        private Color backgroundColor;

        private Font font;

        public LetterPanel(Color backgroundColor, char letter) {
            this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            this.letter = letter;
            this.font = getFont().deriveFont(96f)
                    .deriveFont(Font.BOLD);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 200));
        }

        public void setLetter(char letter) {
            this.letter = letter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(backgroundColor);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            drawCenteredString(g2d, Character.toString(letter),
                    font);
        }

        /**
         * Draw a String centered in the middle of the panel.
         *
         * @param g2d The Graphics2D instance.
         * @param text The String to draw.
         * @param font The Font to draw with.
         */
        public void drawCenteredString(Graphics2D g2d,
                String text, Font font) {
            FontMetrics metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics(font);
            int x = (getWidth() - metrics.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((getHeight() - metrics.getHeight()) / 2) +
                    metrics.getAscent();
            g2d.setFont(font);
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
        }

    }

    public class WordListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            word = (String) wordComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            updateWordPanel(word);
        }

    }

    public class RotateListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            boolean leftSelected = leftBox.isSelected();
            boolean rightSelected = rightBox.isSelected();

            if (leftSelected && rightSelected) {
                word = "OOPS";
                updateWordPanel(word);
                return;
            }

            if (!leftSelected && !rightSelected) {
                return;
            }

            word = (String) wordComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            updateWordPanel(word);

            animation = new Animation(leftSelected);
            new Thread(animation).start();
        }

    }

    public class StopListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (animation != null) {
                animation.setRunning(false);
                animation = null;
            }
        }

    }

    public class Animation implements Runnable {

        private boolean leftSelected;

        private volatile boolean running;

        public Animation(boolean leftSelected) {
            this.leftSelected = leftSelected;
            this.running = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                updatePanel();
                sleep(1000L);
                if (leftSelected) {
                    word = rotateLeft(word);
                } else {
                    word = rotateRight(word);
                }
            }
        }

        public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

        private String rotateLeft(String word) {
            return word.substring(1) + word.substring(0, 1);
        }

        private String rotateRight(String word) {
            return word.substring(word.length() - 1) +
                    word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
        }

        private void updatePanel() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateWordPanel(word);
                }
            });
        }

        private void sleep(long duration) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(duration);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Deliberately left blank

            }
        }

    }

}
```